# Java concurrency - synchronized method doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Well, I'm fighting now with java concurrency I have problem with synchronization. I read a lot questions on stack but there's nothing I can see here.

Class `Checker` checks value of `X` class. It should always be even number (2,4,6,8 ...)

Class X contains `value` which is checked by `Checker.class`. `X` provides `increment` method, which should add 2 to `value` of `X.class`

Class `Y` it's just responsible for calling `inc()` method of `X.class`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Checks for concurrency fails
 * 
 * @author Jones
 * 
 */
class Checker implements Runnable {

    public Checker() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (X.value % 2 != 0){
                System.out.println("Concurrency fail");
                System.out.println(X.value);
            }

            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class X {
    static Integer value = 0;

    static synchronized void inc() {
        value++;
        Thread.yield(); // to accelerate probability of non concurrent
                        // behaviour
        value++;
    }
}

class Y implements Runnable {

    X x;

    public Y(X x) {
        this.x = x;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {

            x.inc();
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(150);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        X x = new X();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            new Y(x);
        }

        new Checker();

    }
}
```

I can't figure why concurrency here fails. That should be correct.
All of the Y threads operating on the same object, that means they should the same lock? Why concurrency here fails? What am I missing?

Comment: You should not start a thread in a constructor - that can create subtle concurrency bugs (although it's not your issue here). So remove `new Thread(this).start();` and use this instead: `for(...) { Y y = new Y(x); new Thread(y).start(); }`

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't create a thread in a constructor. I'd like to add that since this is a learning experience, it would be instructive to use the [executor framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) instead of creating threads directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're accessing `X.value` directly, without any synchronization. You thus can't expect anything about its value.

Introduce a synchronized `getValue()` method, and call this method from the Checker, to have the behaviour you'e expecting.

Comment: You're god damn right. But Checker class just read, doesn't change anything - that means I should synchronize everything what is connected with `value`?
is it true what @assylias saying about the concurrency bugs?

Comment: Yes, every access to a variable that is modified by another thread must be synchronized. Synchronization only prevents other synchronized blocks, synchronized on the same object, from executing concurrently. And yes, assylias is right.